# wp_enqueue_scripts and CSS

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-script

I know `wp_enqueue_script` has the ability to have a dependency which is great. Now what if I can't give it one? 
What if all I want is for it to be the **last** script in the list of generated CSS stylesheets? Themes can be changed out and my dependency is for my stylesheet is to be the last one generated. I want my style to always be the last to override any other stylesheet.

Is there a way to do this without hacking the theme?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the **priority** in hook. **Priority** is the 3rd parameter in the hook. In the following example, `wp_enqueue_scripts` will have priority of 99 which is higher than normal priority. Default priority is 10. So it will load at last

```
function load_last_style() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_last_style', 99 );
```

Comment: Awesome.  How in the world did I miss that!

Comment: Say... What if I have 3 CSS stylesheets and they have to be in a certain order at the very end.  Will using 97, 98, 99 ensure that 97 is first, 98 second, and 99 dead last or is the **priority** not a complete guarantee on add_action?

Comment: You can enqueue the other 2 styles depending on the style hooked on 99 priority (let's call it "style-name" as in the previous example). `wp_enqueue_style( "last-style-name", get_stylesheet_uri(), array("style-name"))`

Comment: I see.  So, as long as I have them in the correct order in the array they won't be processed out of order.